# R Error cannot open the connection using url

Tags: r, url, ftp

I've been working on this code for a while now, basically I need to read the files from [this](ftp://agrofawn-prod01.osg.ufl.edu/pub/howard/georgia/) directory, but I keep getting an error "cannot open the connection", please help me to see which part went wrong?

Hope this code doesn't confuse you much, really wanted to figure out how to get all the files end with .M files(.M09 or .M10) from the above link, if you have better ideas of achieving that, please help, thank you.

```
file.path.in <- file.path("C:", "Users", "agclim", "GAData", fsep=.Platform$file.sep); # Windows                             
file.extension <- c("(\\.M\\d{2})"); 
filename.in.all <- list.files(file.path.in, pattern=paste(file.extension,"+$",sep=""), full.names=FALSE);    
filename.in.all <- sort(filename.in.all, decreasing=FALSE);        
library("gdata");
for (i.in in 1:length(filename.in.all)) { 
    cat(paste("The data in the",filename.in.all[i.in],"file are processing now.", sep=" "), "\n");
    url.conn.server <- url(file.path("ftp://agrofawn-prod01.osg.ufl.edu","pub", "howard","georgia",filename.in.all[i.in],fsep=.Platform$file.sep), open="r", blocking=TRUE, encoding=getOption("encoding"));    
    data.01 <- readLines(url.conn.server, n=-1, ok=TRUE);                     
    unlink(url.conn.server);
    close(url.conn.server);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want the `file.path()` bit in your `url()` call. Try this instead:

```
ftp_url <- "ftp://agrofawn-prod01.osg.ufl.edu/pub/howard/georgia/"
# ...skipping loop logic...
url.conn.server <- url(paste(ftp_url, filename.in.all[i.in], sep=""))
```

Comment: url.conn.server works now, but the following line "data.01 <- readLines(url.conn.server, n=-1, ok=TRUE);" still generate the error :(

Comment: The original error was "The data in the NA file are processing now. 
Error in url(file.path("ftp://agrofawn-prod01.osg.ufl.edu", "pub", "howard",:cannot open the connection", after I tried ur solution, the error becomes "The data in the NA file are processing now. 
Error in readLines(url.conn.server, n = -1, ok = TRUE):cannot open the connection"

Comment: You have `NA` values in your `filename.in.all` vector. You can skip them by checking for `NA` and using continue: `if (is.na(filename.in.all[i.in])) { continue }`

Comment: A little debugging to see why you have `NA` values in the `filename.in.all` vector would be useful, too.

Comment: I used "try" this time: urls <- paste("ftp://agrofawn-prod01.osg.ufl.edu/pub/howard/georgia/",filename.in.all[i.in], sep="")
data1 <- lapply(urls, function(x) {
  tryCatch(read.table(x,header=F,sep=' ',stringsAsFactors=F,colClasses="numeric"),error=function(e) NULL)
})

Comment: there is no error any more, but the result is still "NA", i checked the code, but have no idea which part went wrong, and there is no NA value in the file names...I'm confused

Comment: how can I write table over HTTP,I can read using this url(actual url is not given in comment),but gets error if writing->
write.table(wordToWrite,file=url("http://someurl.com/downloads/original.txt",open="w"),row.names=F,col.names=F)
error-->can only open URLs for readingError in url("http://somerul.com/downloads/original.txt", open = "w") : 
  cannot open the connection

Comment: Sagar, why not just read the data by using -> data <- read.table(""), then save the data as table -> write.table(data,file="filename.csv")

Comment: @more tension, I figured it out, the code is actually right, but I need to run the code in the server, not from my own computer, that's the Na's are coming from, thank you anyway, I'll choose your answer